# Devextreme : dropdown column get closed when just scrolling the list in IE11

Tags: javascript, devexpress, internet-explorer-11, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using **DxDatagrid** of **Devextreme-Angular** in my Angular 6 app.

One of my columns is a select column `(dxo-lookup)`.

It works well in all browsers except in IE11.

There, when opening the select the dropdown appears, but when scrolling down the list it gets closed.

Here is my component view :

```
<dx-data-grid
        #positionsDataGrid
        id="positionsDataGrid"
        [dataSource]="positionsDataSource"
        keyExpr="idObject"
        [allowColumnReordering]="false"
        [showBorders]="true"
        loadPanel="false"
        (onInitNewRow)="onInitNewPosition($event)"
        (onRowUpdating)="logEvent('RowUpdating')"
         <dxi-column dataField="Nom" caption="Nom"></dxi-column>
        <dxi-column
          dataField="edoId"
          caption="Edo"
          [width]="100"
          [allowSorting]="false">
          <dxo-lookup
            [dataSource]="shopsEdosDatasource"
            displayExpr="edoId"
            valueExpr="edoId">
          </dxo-lookup>
          <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Champ obligatoire"></dxi-validation-rule>
        </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on my side, I try to use [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaAly.png), and the output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5ALF.gif), everything works well on my IE 11.1.17134.0. So, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, I suggest you could test [this sample](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/FormEditing/Angular/Light/) on your IE browser, and check whether it works well on your side.

Comment: well i ve IE11 11.0.9600.19155 and even the demao page isn't working well there : https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/FormEditing/Angular/Light/